# Project structure and what apps should be in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

Hello every one I'm learning django and I am starting to master it. I have done many small project in django. But I still want to know what is the base way to structure diango project for advance and latter development. Here are simple case about it.
Let say I want to have a website that have front and backend feature and have the url pattern domain/dj-admin for back end and front and have reguler url like wordpress.
And in my website will have a blog and online store or maybe forum. Now we narrow it little bit. In blog should I create many app that contain post, category, tag and media app or I just create a blog app with post, cat, tag and media in blog model. And should I give every app a `urls.py`. Because I want some url for example.
Next for the backand should I create and project  or just app to handle or user input for a app. And if I create the backend app the url will be nice domain name and the url will loke like this domain/dj-admin/blog/post/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this discussion helps you with your decision.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6101296/4098053

In my opinion there are multiple ways to solve your problem. Every solutions have pro and cons. I think you have to focus of what your apps should do and than search for a solution.